# maximum value column with the condition of another column

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix and I need to calculate for each value of column two maximum column six.

```
25  82  15264   14  -9780   10,6339999999995
25  81  15264   14  -180    16,8469999999976
13  82  79982   14  -46468  17,8979999999989
15  55  7542    2   -14521  30,5426000000015
25  81  4008    6   -2950   27,5500000000107
25  82  4968    8   -3998   34,0590000000113
21  55  25789   7   -9584   15,075800000087
25  81  15840   15  -1964   47,4299999999802
25  82  16416   15  -13070  47,8119999999793
```

the result that I get is:

```
55 -> max = 30.5426

81 -> max = 47.43

82 -> max = 47.8120
```

thank you all

Comment: thanks @Daniel
I tried one of the old posts :(
I settled with the link of the post you consigliat.

Comment: You need the third solution ("Remove gaps; or non-integer labels. General case") and probably also the first output argument of `unique(L)`. If you have problems adapting this solution to your data structure, you may ask a more detailed question. It should at least contain your input data and expected output in valid matlab syntax and some words where you have problems.